# Pip install in editable mode always uninstall existing distribution

Tags: python, installation, pip

Does anyone know why installing a package in [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) will always lead to the uninstallation of existing distribution, regardless on whether the [--ignore-installed](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-i) option is used or not?

```
# Successfully install new package without uninstalling existing distribution
> pip install --prefix /tmp/test --ignore-installed .

# Always attempt to uninstall existing distribution
> pip install --prefix /tmp/test --ignore-installed -e .
```

Looking at the code, it seems to be a designed behavior:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/b98cf9c6c86567e5a9694083d663f031fee22dc0/src/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py#L449

**EDIT:**

I perfectly understand that Python packages can only be imported from one place and that using pip to install packages outside of the site-packages folder can lead to issues, but I assume that people using [--ignore-installed](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-i) and [--prefix](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-prefix) know what they are doing and are aware of the risk.

So why is it possible to install Python packages outside of the site-packages folder without removing installed distribution, but not for editable packages?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something you should ask *pip*'s maintainers directly.

---

If you want my guess (of the top of my head, without trying it) here it is:

It probably has to do with how *editable* installations are implemented. In short they rely on [`.pth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html?highlight=pth) files. And it could well be that those have a lower priority than normal installations. I think I remember seeing the paths from those `.pth` files being placed further down in `sys.path`.

So if in a single environment there are top level packages `something` in both the normal `site-packages` directory and a directory pointed at by a `.pth` file, then it will always be the one from `site-packages` that get found first and imported. To remedy that, it was maybe decided to always uninstall previous installations when `--editable` is specified (just a guess, I have no idea).

On the other hand, using `--ignore-installed` would simply overwrite the already existing `something` directory in `site-packages` (again, my guess, I haven't tested it). So the most recently installed version would be importable (while some remnants of the previously installed version could still be importable, if they exist).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I can see how things can go terribly wrong when mixing `.pth` files and packages. But in my case, all I want is to use pip to install a package in a different prefix without having to worry about the current `site-packages` to be altered, and it really feels like the `--ignore-installed` option should be honored. I just submitted a bug report: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8949. Let see how it goes..

Comment: I am not sure how to help there. I read the bug report. -- Maybe we could take a step back and reconsider why we want to do this in the first place? What is the larger goal that we are trying to achieve here? -- Also would it be possible to install the editable under the alternative different prefix first? -- Would the `--target` option be more helpful? -- Why not create a `venv`?

Comment: As far as I know, `--target` still cannot be used in editable mode (https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/392), but even if it did, what would it change? My goal is to use pip to install packages in a 'quarantine' location without altering existing distributions. This is the project I'm working on: https://github.com/themill/qip. Don't you think that the fact that `--ignore-installed` is not honored is an issue?

Comment: From my point of view... The _editable_ installations have always been a thing apart, I don't think they were ever meant to support all the options such as `--prefix`, `--target`, `--ignore-installed`, etc. Also in general my impression is that these options are not that well specified. It is not a critic of _pip_ I would have a hard time myself figuring out what these options should do in many of the edge cases, people all have different expectations and use cases. It is even more complicated when multiple of those options are combined. --- My advice: install from a_pip_ isolated in a _venv_.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a particular package, it can only be loaded from one place, a single directory on your system. In the case of "editable" (`-e`) installation, this is achieved by putting a link to the package into somewhere in your python distribution - likely into the same place that the previous non-editable version was. To make sure that doesn't clash, and to make sure that an import gets the thing you most recently specified, the previous package is removed.

If you wanted to do something else, you could use PYTHONPATH to point to the directory containing your package (which will be searched *before* the distribution locations), or make your own links; or even manipulate `sys.path` before making the import.

Comment: But the same clash could happen with non-editable libraries, isn't it? Whether the installation is a link or a package, using `--ignore-installed` implies that I know the risk of not letting pip check conflicts, so why this special behavior for editable mode?